# Vue-JS/Axios Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, cors, axios

I'm trying out VueJS and ended up having an issue with Axios and post request. I'm not sure is related to CORS (I had some at the beginning) or simply the way I handle the errors.

> OPTIONS https://127.0.0.1:1880/api/v1/test-endpoint 0 ()
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error    at createError
>   (createError.js?16d0:16)    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError
>   (xhr.js?ec6c:87)

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ohjn.png)

Any idea how I can fix it? I tried with other API online and it works perfectly (that's why I believe is some local setup/config I'm missing, especially with regards to CORS).

Thank you in advance

Comment: As you guessed right this is most likely a cors problem. If you are using a node backend with express you could just include the cors module from npm and everything should work

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, at least for now, I cannot do anything on the backend side...

Comment: You could try to add `crossDomain: true,` to your axios configuration.